# Deploying React App on Github Deploys New App and My Files are Missing

Tags: reactjs, github, create-react-app

I followed all the steps for deploying my React App , but it deploys a New React App on Github and My Components and My Code is not there . 
I added "homepage" and "predeploy" , "deploy" in my Package.json file but when those files got on github , it disappeared .
Here is link to Github repository : https://github.com/cyumair/smartbrainapp

```
      //This is my Package.json 

      {
     "homepage": "https://github.com/cyumair/smartbrainapp",
      "name": "final",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
       "clarifai": "^2.9.0",
       "react": "^16.8.6",
       "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
       "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
       "react-tilt": "^0.1.4",
       "tachyons": "^4.11.1"
       },
       "scripts": {
         "start": "react-scripts start",
         "build": "react-scripts build",
         "test": "react-scripts test",
         "eject": "react-scripts eject",
         "predeploy": "npm run build",
         "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
       },
        "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
        },
       "browserslist": {
         "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
         ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
          ]
        },
         "devDependencies": {
            "gh-pages": "^2.0.1"
            }
          }

     //"predeploy" and "deploy" got disappeared When Uploaded on Github
   "scripts": {
     "start": "react-scripts start",
     "build": "react-scripts build",
     "test": "react-scripts test",
     "eject": "react-scripts eject"
   },
```

Answer (score 2):

your `.gitignore` file currently ignores the `build` folder. that's why your files did not get pushed onto your github repo.

```
# production
# /build <= comment out this line
```

Comment: "production": [
        ">0.2%",
        "not dead",
        "not op_mini all"
    ],//There is no build in production

Comment: I added my whole package.json code in question . Can you tell me what to change in that , I am confused by solution you referred to .

Answer (score 0):

The Problem Is Solved By Changing # production
                                  # /build
                               to # build / in .gitignore file
   and changing "homepage" : "" in package.json file.

And then Running Following Commands In Console :
    $git add .
    $git status (This showed that my missing files were new and needed commit )
    $git commit -m "adding the missing files "
    $git push -u origin master 
    $npm run deploy

I Deleted The Old Repository And Applied The Same Steps on New One , You Can See Working React App at: https://cyumair.github.io/smartbrain/

```
     //package.json file
       "homepage":"https://github.com/cyumair/smartbrainapp"
        //Changed To
       "homepage":"https://cyumair.github.io/smartbrainapp"

     //.gitignore file
       #production
        /build
       //Changed To
       #production
         build/
```